# How can i add cookies in pop when user visits it should be viewed only once, after refresh the page should not be seen

Tags: magento2

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($,modal){
   return function storeswitcher(config, element) {
        var modaloption = {
                type: 'popup',
                modalClass: 'modal-popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                clickableOverlay: true,
                title: 'Simple Modal',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__(yesbutton),
                    class: 'modal-Yes',
                    click: function (){
                        window.location = window.url;
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: $.mage.__(nobutton),
                    class: 'modal-No',
                    click: function (){
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };
            var callforoption = modal(modaloption, $('.callfor-popup'));
            $('.callfor-popup').modal('openModal');
   }
  function getUrl(){
    window.url;
   }
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the localStorage to check

try this code

```
define(["jquery", 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function($, modal) {
return function storeswitcher(config, element) {
    var modaloption = {
        type: 'popup',
        modalClass: 'modal-popup',
        responsive: true,
        innerScroll: true,
        clickableOverlay: true,
        title: 'Simple Modal',
        buttons: [{
            text: $.mage.(yesbutton),
            class: 'modal-Yes',
            click: function() {
                window.location = window.url;
            }
        }, {
            text: $.mage.(nobutton),
            class: 'modal-No',
            click: function() {
                this.closeModal();
            }
        }]
    };
    var callforoption = modal(modaloption, $('.callfor-popup'));
    $('.callfor-popup').modal('openModal');

    if (!localStorage.getItem('popupShown')) {
        $('.callfor-popup').modal('openModal');
        localStorage.setItem('popupShown', true);
    }
}

function getUrl() {
    window.url;
}
```

});

Comment: bharat thank you

Comment: It is working then accept answer..

Comment: okay its working for me